# Operations timeout in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, timeout, connection-pooling

Learning hibernate..please go easy :)

This is my main class i am using to perform operations depending on users choice :

```
package hibernate_tut_emp;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class MyOps {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(" 1 Insert \n 2 Delete \n 3 Update \n 4 Select \n Enter a choice : ");
        int choice = scnr.nextInt();

        SessionFactory sesfact = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sesfact.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Employee emp = new Employee();


        switch (choice) {
        case 1: //insert
            System.out.print("Enter a name : ");
            String name = scnr.next();
            System.out.print("Enter a surname : ");
            String surname = scnr.next();


            emp.setName(name);
            emp.setSurname(surname);

            session.save(emp);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            break;
        case 2://delete
            System.out.print("Enter a name to delete : ");

            String delname = scnr.next();
            Query delQuery = session.getNamedQuery("DeleteByName");
            delQuery.setParameter("name", delname);
            delQuery.executeUpdate();
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            break;
        case 3: //update
            System.out.print("Enter a name to update : ");
            String upname = scnr.next();
            System.out.print("Enter a surname to update : ");
            String surn_name = scnr.next();


            Query q = session.getNamedQuery("UpdateSurnameOfName");
            q.setParameter("name", upname);
            q.setParameter("surname", surn_name);
            q.executeUpdate();
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.print("Enter a name to show details : ");
            String sh_name = scnr.next();

            session = sesfact.getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            Query s_q = session.getNamedQuery("GetDetailsByName");
            s_q.setParameter("name", sh_name);

            List list = s_q.list();
            Iterator it = list.iterator();

            while(it.hasNext()){
                Employee employee = (Employee)it.next();
                System.out.println(employee.getId()+" "+employee.getName()+" "+employee.getSurname());
            }

            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("wrong choice maadi....");
            break;
        }



    }

}
```

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
package hibernate_tut_emp;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    static {

        try {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        } catch (Throwable th) {

            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed" + th);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);

        }

    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        return sessionFactory;

    }
}
```

**Problem**

Till now i executed all the queries individually and they all worked as expected but after i placed all of them inside `switch` i am getting `Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.LockTimeoutException: could not execute statement` error.I assume this has something related to connection pool.
Can someone please tell me exactly how its working here and a way to release connections (*if its a suggested way*) after operation completion?

**Console :**

```
 1 Insert 
 2 Delete 
 3 Update 
 4 Select 
 Enter a choice : 1
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:27 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:27 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:27 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:27 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:27 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:27 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:27 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:27 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate]
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:28 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:28 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:28 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:28 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:28 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:28 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:28 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: hibernate.hib1
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:28 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [id, name, surname]
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:28 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:28 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
Oct 03, 2014 11:50:28 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
Enter a name : mohd.
Enter a surname : salim
Hibernate: insert into hib1 (name, surname, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Oct 03, 2014 11:51:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 41000
Oct 03, 2014 11:51:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
Oct 03, 2014 11:51:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.LockTimeoutException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect$1.convert(MySQLDialect.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at hibernate_tut_emp.MyOps.main(MyOps.java:38)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Your application is locked because it tries to read or write to a row/table that is locked by another, not committed yet, transaction. Make sure you don't have a previous instance of your app still running, or a database browsing tool opened and in the middle of a transaction.

Comment: damn...i had it parallel opened in terminal to check for any update...thanks a lot again...big fan - *as always* !! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @JBNizet  in comments...

I had the table opened in ubuntu terminal as well while trying to do operations on it via hibernate.This was preventing the operation to be done on table.I have close it and its working fine now.

To access the table, i am using `database.tableName` method from other schema to access it now hence avoiding the deadlock!

Comment: how does adding schema helps?

Comment: @Dejel : mmm...didn't get u... are you having any trouble mate...similar to one i posted question for??

Comment: I keep on getting it in the log - and was wondering , where did you add the database.tableName? in terminal?

Comment: @Dejel : no...there must be a while where you would have added a SQL query and mentioned table name as well, just add schema in that as well! :)